# Have to shake the car to get it started

Tags: engine, renault, megane

Renault Megane 1.6 2008 model. I just changed spark plugs and fuel filter thinking that was the issue, but it carries on. The problem is when the car is stagnant and off and when I try starting the car it does not start straight away. I have to pump the fuel a little or shake the entire car for it to start. What could be the problem? The battery is fine, after changing the engine mountings, this problem started due to the engine being freehold.

Comment: re " I have to pump the fuel a little or shake the entire car for it to start.": what do you mean by "pump the fuel" ? did you mean pump the accelerator pedal ? ta